# PHP associative array index undefined

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key

Without looping a set of array keys acquired via array_keys($array), how else can I select the key of an array such that $array["key"] where "key" associates to a second subsequent array -- PHP otherwise outputs a notice stating that "key" is undefined.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Post some code, or at least a plain-text array structure. It's difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies.  The problem I have is testing if the declaration is false, such that e.g. if(!($array["index"] = $value)) { //output error } or by  if($array["index"] != $value) { //output error }

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset), for example `if( isset($array['key'])) ...`

Comment: The key is already set though (e.g. array_push($array["key"], $value) should return true)

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't solve the problem -- PHP is still outputting an undefined response.

Comment: Hmm, suppose I append an associative value by the following means:
    if($array["index"] != $value) { print "Cannot append value"; }
Will that force the value to be false?

Comment: That doesn't append anything, it's just testing the value of it.

Comment: I want to test if the assignment is true, i.e. if it succeeded.

Comment: @Mark Reed this was ultimately a problem with understanding why PHP output a notice declaring that the key was not set.  Ultimately, the problem was indeed the means by which I was testing the truth -- it was actually a preceding piece attempting to assign an array to a key.  So, apologies for inappropriately presenting my query.  However, I would still nonetheless prefer a more thorough understanding of array keys.  Intuitively, I'd simply try the key but for problems requiring comparisons upon the actual value of the key itself and not that to which it associates, array_keys() is required.

Comment: Sorry, @user784446, I still don't understand the question.  Why don't you edit your original question to include a relevant code snippet, as vlzvl asked you to an hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

isset() works for variables, but the error your likely getting is for an undefined key/index.  You'll want to try **array_key_exists()** before trying to use the key (and based on the results, either use or create the key).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php